# How to use column alias define in select query in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Need to use the alias refrence, define  for column in where clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(S.ID)
     , SUBSTR(D.DEPARTENT_ID, 42,INSTR(D.DEPARTENT_ID, '.',2)-8) AS "**DEPT**"
  FROM STUDENT S, DEPARTMENT D
 WHERE S.OBJ LIKE '%' || **DEPT** || '%'
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] before posting a question

Comment: You can't, the alias isn't assigned when the where is evaluated. You have to repeat the selection.

Comment: using oracle database

Answer (score 0):

Have a derived table for the SUBSTR part.

Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Add `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT COUNT(S.ID), DEPT
FROM STUDENT S
    JOIN (SELECT SUBSTR(D.DEPARTENT_ID, 42,INSTR(D.DEPARTENT_ID, '.',2)-8) AS DEPT
          FROM DEPARTMENT) D
    ON S.OBJ LIKE '%' || DEPT || '%'

GROUP BY DEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work since the SELECT statement will be loaded after the WHERE clause.

The order of operations for your query is: FROM -> WHERE -> Aggregations (like the one you used).
You would need to put the aggregation in the where clause as well.